# AngularJS - date range picker - ng model being overridden

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, daterangepicker

Im trying to use the [Angular Bootstrap Daterange Picker](https://github.com/luisfarzati/ng-bs-daterangepicker) , But every instance overrides the ng model to be textual.

This is the very simple code:

```
<input class="input-filter form-control" type="daterange" ng-model="test" ranges="ranges" />
{{test}}
```

Exactly like the 4th example that they provide [**HERE**](http://luisfarzati.github.io/ng-bs-daterangepicker/).

By overriding, I mean that from an object:

```
{"startDate":"2015-11-28T22:00:00.000Z","endDate":"2015-11-28T22:00:00.000Z"}
```

It turns to text:

```
 11/11/2015 - 12/14/2015
```

[**THIS**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Gn5XIYO8Qs&feature=youtu.be) is a 10 seconds video showing this problem. (hope this helps)

And these are the things I load:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/2.1.11/daterangepicker.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/2.1.13/daterangepicker.min.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/2.1.13/moment.min.js
http://luisfarzati.github.io/ng-bs-daterangepicker/ng-bs-daterangepicker.js

Comment: Can you post a demo?

Comment: I tried so hard, but I did not manage to create a demo. not even by copying the demo they have. - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avepaa

Answer (score 1):

I fall into the same issue. I think it caused by the mechanism of updating input value, it probably has been changed in the latest version of daterangepicker (i used v2.1.17 while demo is working with 1.3.17). New daterangepicker has an option `autoUpdateInput`, it might be helpful to set it to false in directive configuration code (https://github.com/luisfarzati/ng-bs-daterangepicker/blob/master/src/ng-bs-daterangepicker.js):

```
//...
options.locale = $attributes.locale && $parse($attributes.locale)($scope);
options.opens = $attributes.opens || $parse($attributes.opens)($scope);

options.autoUpdateInput = false; // Changed row

if ($attributes.enabletimepicker) {
    options.timePicker = true;
    angular.extend(options, $parse($attributes.enabletimepicker)($scope));
}
//...
```

It helps with incorrect model binding, but there is still a bug with rendering -- initial start/end dates do not rendered (input is blank). So in general it looks like someone just needs to move ng-bs-daterangepicker to the latest version of daterangepicker.

Comment: Oh, would you recommend rolling back?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this lightweight pure AngularJS DateRangePicker (no jQuery). https://github.com/tawani/taDateRangePicker